# Can a fluid sim also be a particle emitter?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I'm trying  to understand how to create a small spray of water like in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9LtDzTeb_c
or this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKcI34dhNgY

If it is a particle system, does it uses a fluid simulation as an emiter? What are the settings for this particle system should be? Does this method uses Dinamic Paint?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a tutorial request, which is outside the scope of this site. Please address specific problems, and demonstrate that you've made a good-faith effort in looking up existing research on the very broad topic of "water simulation effects."

Comment: It seems like the creator of that video has made the files available to download. I'd suggest you start there.

Comment: @Matt 
I was looking for any tutorial, but didn't found it, so was hoping to find help from people who work a lot with the particle system. I was surprised by the idea of using a fluid simulation as particle emiter (though I'm not sure the author of the video used this method).

Comment: @cegaton Thank you, I missed the links in the video description.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin That'd be a great way to change this from a tutorial request (which is not allowed) to a specific question (which is allowed): "Can a fluid sim also be a particle emitter?"

Comment: ...though you will want to make sure that question hasn't already been answered so that it doesn't get closed as a duplicate.